# How to test ionic application / v.s on real android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have built a mobile application using `[ Ionic-1 framework / visual studio 2015 ]` to take the geolocation `[ latitude, longitude ]` of the person's device  using ngCordova geolocation plugin .

It depends on the sensor of the person's device to take the coordinates  ..

So i need to know how exactly could i run the application on real android device to get a variable coordinates ..

Some one told me to enable the developer mode in my android device , then connect it with the USB and then write in  `CLI   [ionic run android]`

I tried it , but i got this error

> "uh oh! looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile: cannot
>   find module 'gulp'"

Comment: update npm, remove and reinstall ionic